# How to reduce Trait-values of variadic template parameter to one value?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14, traits, c++17

While experimenting with variadic templates I came to a point where it would be useful to make kind of reduction of trait values to one final value via some operation. The use-case for me is:

```
constexpr bool and(bool lhs, bool rhs){return lhs && rhs;}

struct Foo
{
    template<
        typename ...Ts>
    Foo(
        Ts&&... args)
            noexcept(TraitReduction<std::is_nothrow_move_constructible, and, Ts...>::value)
    {/*...*/}
}
```

The problem is that the STL traits are all single template typed.
My current working solution is:

```
template<
    template<typename> class TraitT,
    bool (*Operator)(bool,bool),
    typename T1,
    typename ...Ts>
struct TraitReduction
{
    static bool const value = TraitT<T1>::value;
};

template<
    template<typename> class TraitT,
    bool (*Operator)(bool,bool),
    typename T1,
    typename T2,
    typename ...Ts>
struct TraitReduction<
    TraitT,
    Operator,
    T1,
    T2,
    Ts...>
{
    static bool const value = (*Operator)(
        TraitT<T1>::value,
        TraitReduction<TraitT, Operator, T2, Ts...>::value);
};
```

My question is if the STL gives some standardized (probably more convenient) solutionfor that task? And of course I would be happy to here some comments on my current solution, what is bad or what could be better.

Comment: `noexcept((is_nothrow_move_constructible<Ts>{} and ...))`

Comment: This particular case looks like a job for [`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) but if you're looking for a more generalized approach then it's not enough

Comment: You know that `and` is another spelling of `&&`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is linear in term of instantiations (and without the advantage of short-circuit)

You may do it in less instantiations (and still without short-circuit)

```
template <bool...> struct bools{};

template <template <typename> Trait, typename ... Ts>
struct all_of : std::is_same<bools<true, Trait<Ts>::value...>,
                             bools<Trait<Ts>::value..., true>> {};
```

You may use `std::conjunction` which is linear, but with short-circuit.

c++17 and folding expression has nice syntax, has less instantiations (but without short-circuit (for instantiation)):

```
(Trait<Ts>::value && ...)
```

Comment: Comparison of two types (specializations of a class templates with long template argument lists) is linear on number of *template-names* and *type-ids* (those of them, which is not *template-ids*) and `std::conjunction` is also linear. Which to prefer?

Comment: It maybe even better to use type alias for `all_of` definition: `template< ... > using all_of = typename std::is_same< ... >::type;`